# Uninstall rails on mac and do another clean install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Current ruby: 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0] 
rails: 4.0.0

Every time I give any rails command, I get following message first -

```
/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-     1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
```

How do I get rid of this? I'm tired of using sudo everytime. Is there a way I could uninstall my current installation of rails and do fresh install right way where I don't have to use sudo anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777`

Means anybody can read,write and execute files in `/usr/local`

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/local
```

Should solve your issues, but for better understanding look at http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Comment: Not working for me. I'm getting same errors while starting rails server

Comment: @Aniruddha can you put the output of the command in quotes "ls -ld /usr/local"

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x@ 15 aniruddhabarapatre1  502  510 Dec 18 22:24 /usr/local`